# in visual studio c++ debug, how to convert scentific float value in immediate window and locals window

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

in visual studio c++ how to convert scentific float value in immediate window and locals window, e.g. 2.6784184492221229e+271
(including denomalized number).

for example, in Locals window, VS c++ would show type double as 2.6784184492221229e+271
and in immediate, if I type, ?vara, it would show as 2.6784184492221229e+271

how can we convert it to a direct readable value? 1.8 (sorry I don't know what it is called).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you want it to display: 26784184492221229000000000000000000...? Or are you saying that you want it displayed like: 2.6784184492221229e+271?